# I can not see the mschart image when another folder

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, mschart

mschart image not display 
When the web page is at the root then It's normal.
when in another folder image not display

web.config

aspx page
url = ~/IMS/Frm_PartHisManager.aspx

dim imagePath As String

imagePath = "../IMS/"

Chart1.ImageLocation = imagePath + "ChartPic_#SEQ(300,3)"

Comment: web.config<add key="ChartImageHandler" value="storage=file;timeout=30;dir=c:\TempImageFiles\;"/>

Comment: <add name="ChartImageHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" path="ChartImg.axd" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>

Comment: pls share a `tree . -L 4` in the root folder.

Comment: https://localhost:44393/test01.aspx    is succese     https://localhost:44393/ims/test01.aspx    is  false

Comment: ImageLocation="~/TempImages/ChartPic_#SEQ(300,3)"